# How to avoid converting iQueryable to a List?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have the following (working) code:

```
 List<Location> allLocations = new List<Location>();
 using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
 {
     Login currentLogin = GetCurrentLogin(context);
     if (currentLogin != null)
     {
         foreach (var customer in currentLogin.Customers)
         {
             allLocations.AddRange(customer.Locations);
         }
     }
 }
 return allLocations.AsQueryable();
```

`MyContext` and its objects live within the entity framework. `Customers` and `Locations` are `ICollection<>`-Properties

This code works as expected, returning all locations from the users' Customers

But as you can see, I add the entity `customer.Locations` to a `List`.

At the end of that function I return that generated list as `IQueryAble` to be able to continue using `LinQ`-Expressions on the result.

Because of performance reasons I would like to skip the List<>-Step and stay inside `IQueryAble`

Is it possible?

Comment: Why are you returning `IQueryable<T>` in the first place? You can use LINQ expressions on a `List<T>` just fine. Of course they're all going to work on the in-memory list instead of going to the database, but it's not like your current code would work any different either.

Comment: That's why I did not like my code, And that is what I meant with "performance reasons"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `List<Location> allLocations` to `IQueryable<Location> allLocations`.

Then you can do something like `allLocations = currentLogin.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.Locations).AsQueryable()`.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the whole thing without a `foreach` loop by using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)? That way you can keep everything as an `IEnumerable`:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    Login currentLogin = GetCurrentLogin(context);
    if (currentLogin != null)
    {
        return currentLogin.Customers.SelectMany(c => c.Locations);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful about using an IQueryAble or IEnumerable after having disposed the MyContext() as they are lazy loaded.

The query won't actually be evaluated until it is used in whichever function called it, but by then the context will have been disposed and an exception will be thrown.

Hence probably why the method originally populated the returned results into a `List` as it forced the query to be evaluated while the context was still active.

Comment: You are right about that. I already changed the method and use context as a method parameter.

Comment: good to hear. just be aware that, from my experience, the longer a context is kept around the slower it gets, particularly if you are doing updates and inserts.